# What is the best way to declare function variables when called by multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system

There is a function which must be running for a long time.
suppose  the function is called by multiple threads. The function has many  variables which most of them are std::string.
There is two possible way to declare function variables: 
 1-

```
 void Test()
 {
    std::string s1; s1.reserve(500);
    std::string s2; s2.reserve(500);
    std::string s3; s3.reserve(500);
    std::string s4; s4.reserve(500);
    std::string s5; s5.reserve(500);

    for(;;)
    {
        s1= Read_from_file();
        s2= Read_from_file2();
        s3= s1.substr(0,Snaplength);
        s4= s2.substr(0,Snaplength);
        s5= s1+ s2;
        .
        .
        .       
    }

 }
```

2-

```
    for(;;)
    {
        std::string s1= Read_from_file();
        std::string s2= Read_from_file2();

        std::string s3= s1.substr(0,Snaplength);
        std::string s4= s2.substr(0,Snaplength);
        .
        .
        .       
    }

 }
```

As said earlier the function must be running for a long time.

which way is better in term of time complexity when i need to call my function by many threads?

[Added:]
suppose i need to call my function for 1000000 times and want to do it as fast as possible. one possible way is to run the function by multiple threads, but Afaik, it is not always possible to achieve better performance by running the function by multiple threads. in which case adding threads may be more faster?

OS= GNU/Linux

Comment: If you're using C++11, almost certainly the second one.

Comment: The local variables aren't shared between threads, so I don't get what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference as far as the algorithmic complexity in time goes; the second version might(!) be a little bit more efficient, but I'd prefer it for different reasons: it reduces the scope of the variables and thus improves encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it **really** efficient, avoid creating strings on the stack *altogether*. When you assign the strings, it may perform heap allocation which requires synchronization and will be slow.

The fastest would be to preallocate private memory to be used by each thread, and instead of strings use memcpy and similar whenever possible. Do you actually need these strings, or just the raw data?

```
    std::string s1= Read_from_file();
    // can be replaced by
    fread(private_memory_area[thread_number], 1, datasize, file)

    std::string s3= s1.substr(0,Snaplength);
    // can be replaced by
    memcpy(private_memory_area_2[thread_number], private_memory_area[thread_number], Snaplength);
```

Sorry if this seems complex, but you asked for it to be "as fast as possible", and std::string is not efficient at all. If the strings are big, it will be worthwhile to use this method.